# Error on mounting BTRFS volume on Precise

Tags: mount, btrfs

I use a 12.04 (Precise) fully updated (kernel `3.2.0-58-generic x86_64`). In other partitions, I installed the Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty (Alpha version) to try out. I can't boot into the Trusty system any more. I guess it's something related with some grub configuration I modified or some error in booting the root partition (/).

I want to access some file in the /home, which is a BTRFS partition over luks. I can open the device in luks, but when I try to mount it in the precise, I get some error. This is what it outputs to the `dmesg`:

```
btrfs: disk space caching is enabled
BTRFS: couldn't mount because of unsupported optional features (60).
btrfs: open_ctree failed
```

I tried to mount as read-only but it didn't work also. Does someone how could I access this from the precise? I'll need this so much when I began to change from my old Precise to the Trusty install later.

Comment: This means that Trusty is _slightly different_ from Precise. I advice you to fix broken Trusty installation instead of trying to fetch something from unsupported filesystem.

Comment: @Danatela Note that btrfs is supported both by the software and by the community.

Comment: @ignis, I meant the unsupported version of the FS. Nevertheless, thanks for elaboration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
BTRFS: couldn't mount because of unsupported optional features
```

This means that this btrfs filesystem was created with new, non-backwards-compatible features that the old Precise kernel did not have when it was released. These "features" are not visible to the user, they are improvements to the on-disk structure of the filesystem.

These features are optional: Trusty can create a btrfs that is readable from Precise (without those features), depending on the parameters that are passed to the `mkfs.btrfs` program. 
It seems that the Trusty installer enabled those features, which I think should be reported as a bug against Trusty, since it prevents interoperability.

The numeric code of the features is `60`, [that means](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/fs/btrfs/ctree.h?id=refs/tags/v3.13.5#n519): extended inode references and big metadata. [As far as I can say](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/btrfstune.8.html), there is no way to disable extended inode references, thus you cannot make this filesystem readable by older kernels anymore.

To read the files,

- open the partition from a Trusty Live DVD (or Saucy? Saucy supports extended inode references, but I don't know about the other feature)
- In theory, another option is to update your kernel in Precise with the Saucy one from the Enablement Stack, but that is equivalent to trying Saucy.

To reinstall Trusty so that its partition will be readable by Precise,

- either reformat from within Precise (will delete all the contents). Then, when you are at the Trusty installer, choose that partition for `/` but tell it not to format.
- or choose the ext4 filesystem instead of btrfs, in the installer.

Comment: Thanks. The Enablement Stack sounds promising. I didn't know about it and seems so be exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: I tried The Enablement Stack, but the installation failed and left me with a broken system. When restoring it, I used the `Ubuntu 12.04.2` iso image, which I found out to be able to open and mount BTRFS partition.

Comment: Good to hear that. For completeness: note that [Ubuntu 12.04.2 has Quantal Enablement Stack built-in](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop-12.04.2#LTS_Hardware_Enablement_Stack).